# How does the leaver penalty work for Competitive play?

Tags: overwatch

It hasn't been explained well on Blizzard's support page, and I just wanted to know the length and severity of leaving games of competitive play on Overwatch. I know it gives you a 75% EXP reduction and suspension from competitive play, but I don't understand how long each suspension cooldown lasts. As far as I know, I've gotten a 30 minute and 2 hour suspension before.

Comment: You may want to try editing your question with proper spelling and grammar.

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out what you can get away with, just stop leaving games. That way you don't have to worry about getting banned. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Blizzard forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745234477#post-6):

> - If you leave too many games and your “games played” vs “games completed” percentage falls below our required threshold, you will
>     receive a warning message (this percentage is calculated based on your
>     20 most recent games).
> - If you continue to leave games after receiving a warning (which will display in the lower left-hand corner of your screen), you will
>     incur a 75% EXP penalty on all future games.
> - The penalty isn’t time-based, but instead will be removed once you complete enough games to raise your “games played” vs “games
>     completed” percentage above our required threshold (again, this
>     percentage is calculated based on your 20 most recent games).
> - If you disconnect or are removed due to inactivity from a game, it will count the same as if you leave the game intentionally.
> - If you leave a game before the “Assemble Your Team” phase is over (i.e. before you enter your starting spawn rooms):
>
>   - It won’t count as a game played
>   - You will not be considered a “leaver” in this scenario
> - If you leave a game after the match ends (i.e. after you see the VICTORY/DEFEAT screen):
>
>   - It will count as a game played—and if your team won, it will count as a win
>   - You will not be considered a “leaver” in this scenario
> - If you leave a game after the “Assemble Your Team” phase is over, but before the match ends:
>
>   - It will count as a game played
>   - You will be considered a “leaver” in this scenario